# Does HHVM support IMAP?

Tags: imap, hhvm

I have a new ubuntu server running HHVM that I just installed my PHP application on. Everything seems to work fine except one aspect.

I have a button that queries an external e-mail box, and downloads the attachments to the server, however when I run that function I get:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_sort()`

I know there's usually a module for it, but I don't know how to check for it on this setup.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You run what function?

Comment: The function the button fires, it connects to the inbox, sorts and gets the latest email than downloads the attachment.

Comment: Do you think you should post the function that causes the error message?

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary because the area runs fine on php 5.4, but switching to hhvm caused this error. I was just wondering if there was something with hhvm I had to enable or something.

Comment: From [elsewhere](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap#comment-499054): Your server has not installed the IMAP extension, it should be enabled for the use of all IMAP functions, in your php.ini search the line: `;extension=php_imap.dll` and restart apache service. Good Luck

Comment: Wow, so many of you people didn't read that he was talking about HHVM and not PHP...

Answer (score 1):

The [HHVM documentation for `imap_sort`](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.imap-sort.php) very loudly proclaims

## NOT SUPPORTED IN HHVM

so no, HHVM does not currently support this function.

Comment: The link you posted redirects to PHP's website. Is this the intended link or has it changed since you posted it? It appears to me at HHVM has been updated to support IMAP, although I'm still experiencing the same result.

Comment: The link has changed in the nearly 1 year since I posted this; the HHVM docs now redirect standard PHP functions to the PHP docs, instead of having a fork of them.